# Convergence in the space $C([a,b],M_1(\mathbb R))$.

Tags: probability, general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $M_1(\mathbb R)$ be the space of probability measures on $\mathbb R$ with the weak(-*-)topology:

$\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ iff $\int f(x) \mu_n(dx) \rightarrow \int f(x) \mu(dx)$ for all $f \in C_b(\mathbb R)$ continuous and bounded functions. (Portmanteau-Theorem)

A corresponding metric is the Lévy–Prokhorov metric $\rho_{LP}$. (Maybe also others?)

Now we look at the space $C([a,b],M_1(\mathbb R))$ of continuous functions into $M_1$ with the uniform topology.

Hence

$G_n,G \in C([a,b],M_1(\mathbb R))$ with $G_n \rightarrow G$
iff

$\sup_{y \in [a,b]} \rho_{LP} ( G_n(y),G(y)) \rightarrow 0$

**Question:**

Does $G_n \rightarrow G$ in $C([a,b],M_1(\mathbb R))$ imply that for all $f \in C_b([a,b] \times \mathbb R)$

$$\sup_{y \in [a,b]} \left| \int_{\mathbb R} f(y,x) G_n(y)(dx) - \int_{\mathbb R} f(y,x) G(y)(dx) \right| \rightarrow 0$$

?

i.e. is something like Portmanteau-Theorem also here valid?